# Realtek wifi driver problem rtl8723be weak signal

Tags: wireless, realtek

I have HP i3 laptop and I recently install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I could not detect my home wifi. Later I found out that the wifi gets connected only if Im like a feet near the router. It does not work even 5 feet away, where in windows 7 (dual boot) it works even 12-15 feet away. Please help me fix this. I tried every solution given in similar posts. But nothing worked.

Comment: If you have Secure Boot enabled, the driver may not install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this

open terminal and run

```
iwconfig
```

Note down the wlp number, in my case it was wlp13s0

Now download the driver from this [link](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/tree/rock.new_btcoex)

And unzip and copy it to the Desktop. The final result should be like you should have a folder named ***rtlwifi_new-rock.new_btcoex***  in Desktop.

Now go back to terminal and cd to that folder. that is

```
cd Desktop
cd rtlwifi_new-rock.new_btcoex
```

Now run these commands 1 by 1

```
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be
sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=2
```

By now your wifi should be strong and start working, but follow below commands to make the settings permanent

```
sudo ip link set wlp13s0 up
sudo iw dev wlp13s0 scan
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/50-rtl8723be.conf
```

This should fix the wifi and no reboot required.

Comment: This way you will have to re-install the driver after each kernel upgrade. I packed this driver as a DKMS PPA.

Comment: You don't need the rock.new_btcoex branch either, it was merged with the master branch months ago.  I think Pilot6's dkms.conf file is in there now also

Comment: When I run ``sudo ip link set wlp13s0 up `` i get "Cannot find device 'wlp13s0' "

Comment: Not all devices are named wlp13s0. So check the name of your device using the command _iwconfig_

Comment: in my iwconfig. I can only see lo and eno1. How can I install wlp13s0 ??

Comment: @mac after run `iwconfig`, I only have `lo` and `enp2s0` without any `wlp13s0`, how can I install it? @Jishad Have you fixed your problem? Can you show me the answer? Thanks

Comment: @huynhsamha  can you check if your devie supports wifi/wireless ? Also , even if it shows enp2s0, does it show the propterites for it ?

Comment: @mac I've used Ubuntu 16.04 in a long time with wireless, but today my laptop lost the wireless interface without any `wlan` number when run `iwconfig`. I dont know how to fix this problem. I also install other Ubuntu 18 on the same laptop and it also no. How can I download and install it? Tnx.

Comment: @huynhsamha  then I think there is a hardware issue. with wifi card must have burnt. Check for hardware devices and see if you can list wifi card and is no showing any issues.